# Sequelize createdAt/updatedAt timestamps (milliseconds) being rounded to 000?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sequelize.js

I'm trying to unit test a `createJob` function.

I'm comparing the `job` object returned as part of the `createJob` response, to the object that's returned when querying the database for that newly created object.

The first object has milliseconds included in the timestamps, the second has them rounded to `000`. `createdAt` and `updatedAt` are automatically created, and don't actually seem to store the milliseconds at all.

`actual` = result of `createJob(...)`

`expected` = result of `getJob(5)`

```
  showDiff: true,
  actual: {
    id: 5,
    companyId: 2,
    title: 'Future Markets Designer',
    wage: 80000,
    location: 'East Paolohaven',
    description: 'Dynamic',
    featured: false,
    updatedAt: 2021-08-03T15:53:44.335Z,
    createdAt: 2021-08-03T15:53:44.335Z
  },
  expected: {
    id: 5,
    title: 'Future Markets Designer',
    wage: 80000,
    location: 'East Paolohaven',
    description: 'Dynamic',
    featured: false,
    createdAt: 2021-08-03T15:53:44.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-08-03T15:53:44.000Z,
    companyId: 2
  },
  operator: 'deepStrictEqual'
```

Not sure the best way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll leave this here in case it helps someone else. Not sure if it's the best way to do it, but explicitly adding `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fixed the issue:

```
createdAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE(3),
    allowNull: false,
},
updatedAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE(3),
    allowNull: false,
}
```